# The math! It's overflowing!

Tags: bug, mathjax, design, comments

See what happens if you expand the comments on [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147016/homotopy-groups-other-than-pi-1-what-are-they-good-for), we get this prime example of a math overflow:

[image]

Of course, this is due to a \$ problem, but still, it seems to be a flaw in the CSS that this is possible.

Note that the  overflowing math *does* get cut off, eventually, at the edge of the sidebar. Shouldn't the `overflow` property be set up such that it gets cut off before that happens? The whole comment thread gets reflowed if there is one broken comment.

The same seems to apply to answers, math is allowed to overflow into the far edge of the sidebar.

This happens on Chrome Stable and FF 25.

*Remark (added on Oct 4, 2015):* This bug report appears to be still pending.

Comment: This has happened for ages. The fix so far has been is not to do it :-)

Comment: Interestingly, I cannot edit that comment because its edit link is under something else (and one cannot get there by tabbing because of the SE fascination with :hover...)

Comment: I hid the thing on top using Firebug :-)

Comment: Math Overflow? It's not a bug, it's a feature! :-)

Comment: Here is a link to meta.MSE discussion, where Willie Wong suggested a way how to get to edit/delete button in such cases: [Comments layout break if Math expression is too long](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/comments-layout-break-if-math-expression-is-too-long). (Several other discussions about the same problem are linked there.)

Comment: @Manishearth: Martin posted a link from MSE to your comment above as "another way" of editing comments when such breakage happens. It is a shame that it is gone!

Comment: This is a long standing bug that happens with code-formatted markdown in comments too. Just noting that we've seen this, but I'm not sure about a fix.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is caused by the fact that if a comment contains many consecutive characters without a space, the Stack Exchange software inserts invisible unicode character  (\unicode{x200C}\unicode{x200B} Zero Width Non-Joiner, Zero Width Space). in the comment.

There are several posts on Mathematics Meta with various suggestions what to do when this problem appears to make at least edit or delete button visible. It probably does not make sense to repeat all of them here, let me give links instead:

- [My comments got stretched across the screen, and it won't allow me to edit or delete the comment either.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24987)
- [Comments layout break if Math expression is too long](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2652)
- [Formatting bug: long mathjax or code blocks break entire post or page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13603)
- [Too long LaTex formulae not shown in comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5137)
- Some suggestions how to handle this are also given on the corresponding bug report on Meta Stack Exchange: [Comment “spreaded” all over the webpage - unable to edit, unable to delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281614)