# Long MathJax in comment breaks linewrapping throughout the comment thread

Tags: bug, mathjax, comments

A picture is worth a thousand words; here is what I am talking about, from the comments on [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215165/why-does-dn-exp-x-x-1-dxn-only-have-n-positive-real-zeroes).

[image]

By posting a very long formula into MathJax, not only have I caused my own comment to run off the edge of the screen (which perhaps I deserved), but the same has happened to all the other comments in the thread.

Firefox 38.2.0, OS X 10.8.5. Bug also occurs in Safari 6.2.7.

**UPDATE** I just deleted the comment, since it was inconveniencing others in the thread. Hopefully, this has left enough data to reproduce the bug.

*Remark (added on Oct 4, 2015):* This bug report appears to be still pending.

Comment: The bug also occurs in Chrome.

Comment: Is this different from http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1148/the-math-its-overflowing ?

Comment: @quid I agree, that is the same.